# got error and exceptions using HtmlUnit in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, htmlunit

I just wrote simple code in Java (using Eclipse editor with OS X, jdk1.8.0_25.jdk):

```
String url = "http://www.delfi.lt";
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
webClient.closeAllWindows();
System.out.println("Done!");
```

and got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" ======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[1546] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[script in http://www.delfi.lt/ from (1545, 32) to (1548, 10)] message=[TypeError: Cannot find function getElementsByClassName in object [object HTMLDocument]. (script in http://www.delfi.lt/ from (1545, 32) to (1548, 10)#1546)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function getElementsByClassName in object [object HTMLDocument]. (script in http://www.delfi.lt/ from (1545, 32) to (1548, 10)#1546)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:705)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:620)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:591)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:566)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:975)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:349)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:409)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:274)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:288)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:741)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:701)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3126)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2093)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:920)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:965)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:247)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:193)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:468)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:342)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:407)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:392)
    at ClickingDelfi.submitComment(ClickingDelfi.java:26)
    at Main.run(Main.java:28)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function getElementsByClassName in object [object HTMLDocument]. (script in http://www.delfi.lt/ from (1545, 32) to (1548, 10)#1546)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3629)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3613)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3634)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3650)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3714)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2233)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2215)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1333)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:411)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3057)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:582)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:690)
    ... 34 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function getElementsByClassName in object [object HTMLDocument]. (script in http://www.delfi.lt/ from (1545, 32) to (1548, 10)#1546)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3629)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3613)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3634)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3650)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3714)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2233)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2215)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1333)
    at script(script in http://www.delfi.lt/ from (1545, 32) to (1548, 10):1546)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:411)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3057)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:582)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:690)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:620)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:591)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:566)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:975)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:349)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:409)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:274)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:288)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:741)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:701)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3126)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2093)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:920)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:965)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:247)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:193)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:468)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:342)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:407)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:392)
    at ClickingDelfi.submitComment(ClickingDelfi.java:26)
    at Main.run(Main.java:28)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

Using url as https://www.google.lt it worked. Is it only working with certain pages? Is there any alternatives that can be used with the url I use?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [WebClientOptions](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClientOptions.html) to get around exceptions thrown by the Script engine. This can be done via:

```
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

Alternatively, you may also disable Javascript entirely:

```
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

Comment: however, if javascript is disabled, how to evaluate javascript using HtmlUnit?

Comment: Well, I don't know your exact use case, so if you want to evaluate or test Javascript, don't disable it and only set `setThrowExceptionsOnScriptError` to `false`. Depending on the Javascript error and your use case, the error might be negligible or not. You might also want to try switching the `BrowserVersion` (for instance, with `BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24` I did not get any exceptions). Otherwise, I'm afraid you are not left with many options aside from fixing the site itself or using another tool.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue but I was using the `HtmlUnitDriver` rather than using the `HtmlUnit` class directly. Because the `HtmlUnitDriver` does not make the `getWebClient` class public I resolved this issue by creating a `HtmlUnitDriverWrapper` add added a `getWebClientOptions()` method to it.

Once I did that I was able to disable javascript exceptions with the following command.

```js
driver.getWebClientOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

Unfortunately for me this simply resulted in the test case failing silently so I instead commented out all assertions after the error and reported the javascript error to the dev team as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final String url = "http://www.delfi.lt";

    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(40_000);

        System.out.println(page.asXml());
    }
}
```

Cannot find function getElementsByClassName in object [object HTMLDocument]

seems to point to a really really old version of HtmlUnit. But also with the latest one this page produces many js errors, but maybe there is enough code executed to get the results you need.